# Assert property isn't undefined when function that accesses it is called in only one place

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to typecheck code that looks like this

```js
type MyObj = {
  someProp?: string
}

function getStuff(obj: MyObj): string {
  return 'hello ' + obj.someProp
}

let x
if (obj.someProp) {
  x = getStuff(obj)
}
```

but the type checker complains that in `getStuff`, `obj.someProp` might be undefined. Do I really have to do a runtime check twice? Do I just re-write the code to do the check in `getStuff()`

```js
type MyObj = {
  someProp?: string
}

function getStuff(obj: MyObj): string | undefined {
  if (obj.someProp === undefined) {
    return undefined
  }
  return 'hello ' + obj.someProp
}

const x = getStuff(obj)
```

or is there another way?

Comment: Consider that you might use the `getStuff` function in _other locations_ that aren't guarded by that check. Unless you put the check within the `getStuff` function itself, TS will have no way of knowing what it is receiving, except that it will match the type you specified, where `someProp` is declared optional (and so you have to handle the case where it is missing).

Comment: @CRice but then I have to make `getStuff` return `string | undefined` and then my normal code complains (which I still wrap in an `if` too) that it can return `undefined` so I can set the result to a `string`-typed variable. Or I have to make it return the empty string or some other throw away value

Comment: Yes, this is a good thing. Do not allow your types to lie to you. If the function can possibly return `undefined` then `undefined` should be part of it's return type. If you really need to avoid the undefined in the return signature, try restricting the parameters so it doesn't allow you to pass a value that would produce an `undefined` return. Eg: `getStuff(obj: Required<MyObj>)`.